# What to do about a recurring bug?

Tags: support

When reviewing Low Quality posts via the review queue and hitting "Recommend deletion", I was wondering if there was any difference between selecting "No comment needed" and any of the other comments already selected by another reviewer. I had never noticed any effect, not even going back to the post (usually an answer).

The answer to this question ["What happens when I add a “comment for the author” that's already there?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261315/1307905), tells me that a selection, in the "Add a comment for the author?" box, of a comment that is already there upvotes that comment. That has not been the case for any of my reviews the week, and I paid explicit attention to quite a few of them (opening the link in another tab and refreshing after a few minutes). One of the answers today was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8030775) (now removed), where I selected the "Please don't add thank you.." comment, waited a couple of minutes to see if the upvote would take place and refreshed the page to see this:

[image]

other votes to delete this removed the answer after 20 minutes or so, the upvote of the comment, if it had taken place, never was shown in that time.

This seems like a bug, and that bug has been reported before in this question ["Upvoting comments in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue does not actually upvote the comment [closed]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283491/1307905), which was answered by its OP as "I don't know what happened, but it works fine now. I swear it was bugged ten hours ago...".

So this bug is back, at least for me, and over multiple days. What should I do about such a bug that was already reported:

- File a new report (with the change it gets closed as duplicate)?
- Gather "evidence" (links to reviews, of answers that might now be removed, where this did not work) and file a new bug report with a month or so worth of daily occurrences?
- Try to reopen that closed bug report mentioned above (which, I fear, might never happen)?
- Comment on the closed bug report and/or the original answer that mentions the upvotes?
- Some other action?

(Just in case someone is wondering about the non-upvote capabilities: I had not hit my max upvotes for comments for the day and was able to upvote comments by hand after such occurences. This does not work on SO as well as U&L, and with different comments for different questions selected. If I select a different comment, it is being added).